# Checkboxes become invisible when igGrid row slected

Tags: javascript, checkbox, infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I have a couple of checkboxes in my igGrid. If the checkboxes are set to true and i hover over the row, the igGrid shows them as unchecked whereas regarding the data, they are still set to true. When i select some other row, the grid starts showing them correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

It would be very difficult to determine what is causing this kind of issue without a working sample. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/zdravko/52tqcyu8/1/) jsfiddle example is showing a basic configuration of igGrid with bool dataType column.

If you want to distinguish the checked/unchecked boxes you can add this style:

```
.ui-igcheckbox-container > span {
            border: 2px solid grey;
        }
```

In order to help you further update the sample to show us the issue that you are facing.